# Why does ITypeSymbol.ToString() return a wrong value for a multidimensional array in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

My aim is to get `TypeSyntax` by `ITypeSymbol` with Roslyn.
I do it this way:

```
SF.ParseTypeName(myTypeSymbol.ToString())
```

This approach works fine until we get `myTypeSymbol` of multidimensional array in input.
Example:
Say `myExpression` is of type `int[,]`
in this case

```
SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(myExpression).Type.ToString();
```

returns `int[*,*]` instead of `int[,]`.
So `SF.ParseTypeName("int[*,*]")` returns wrong `TypeSyntax`.
In the result `TypeSyntax` `rank.sizes` are parsed as `PrefixUnaryExpressionSyntax` instead of `OmittedArraySizeExpressionSyntax`.

So the questions are why does `myTypeSymbol.ToString()` returns `int[*,*]`? and is there any workaround to get correct `TypeSyntax` for multidimensional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control the string representation of a symbol (to be programming language specific, for example), you need to use a `SymbolDisplayFormat` and feed it to 'symbol.ToDisplayString()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I managed to achieve the desired result with `ParseTypeName( myTypeSymbol.ToDisplayString(new SymbolDisplayFormat(typeQualificationStyle: SymbolDisplayTypeQualificationStyle.NameAndContainingTypesAndNamespaces)))`